# PHP MySQL: Join 3 tables but

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, errorcode_table, description_table, and customer_table.

The query below will display all records that are in the errorcode_table and I have an inner join that will also display the customer_table as per the serial number in both tables.

```
SELECT 

errorcode_table.error, 
errorcode_table.deviceserialnumber, 
customer_table.serialnumber,
customer_table.customer,

FROM errorcode_table 

INNER JOIN customer_table

ON errorcode_alert_table.deviceserialnumber = customerinfo_table.serialnumber
```

Now I want to also display the description of the error code as well, here's my attempt:

```
SELECT 

errorcode_table.error, 
errorcode_table.serialnumber, 
customer_table.serialnumber,
customer_table.customer,
description.serialnumber
description.info

FROM errorcode_table 

INNER JOIN customer_table
RIGHT JOIN description_table

ON errorcode_table.deviceserialnumber = customer_table.serialnumber
ON errorcode_table.deviceserialnumber = description_table.serialnumber
```

Now I'm not getting any records. Please assist.

Comment: `I'm not getting any records` ... worse than this, you should be getting an error because that query uses invalid syntax.  The `ON` clause for each join should appear immediately after each join, not all at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ON` clause for each join should appear immediately after each join condition.  And you can introduce table aliases to make the query easier to read.

```
SELECT 
    e.error, 
    e.serialnumber,
    c.serialnumber,
    c.customer,
    d.serialnumber,
    d.info
FROM errorcode_table e
INNER JOIN customer_table c
    ON e.deviceserialnumber = c.serialnumber
RIGHT JOIN description_table d
    ON e.deviceserialnumber = d.serialnumber;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your advice I know I am worst at formating. It would be great if I can learn from you. I definitely follow you :)